# Employee shortlisting

Tags: java, php, algorithm, programming-languages, evolutionary-algorithm

I have n numbers of things in queue and I have to find best possible things against open criteria categories C { X,Y Z) ( here X,Y,Z are C variants ). What will be the best suggested generic algorithm in least time complexity  ?

Eg:

Lets say an company post a job in C++,C,Banking domain,STL, 5-10 Year...so on.
100 people applied for the same position. Some have exp in C, some in C++, Java.. Some have C, C++, telecom domain...and so on. My question here is : how to find the best employee? How to rank them?

Comment: all i could really suggest here is to assign values to each criteria and take the sum of the ones that are met

Comment: more keywords in resume != best employee. You need to look at a better way to hire ;)

Comment: hello Zengr ,I am designing filter as per employer prospective. Have u better Idea to share on candidate shortlisting on the basis of resume only. We welcome your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need some sort of *stemming*, which translates each criteria word(s) into a canonical criteria word(s), to get criteria to match better.

For example:

- Bank => bank
- Banks => bank
- Banking => bank
- Financial sector => bank
- Java => Java
- JSE => Java + Swing
- J2SE => JSE => Java + Swing
- RHEL => RHEL + linux

I'd start from the Lucene English stemmer and extend that.

Answer (score 1):

Rough idea,

Consider company requirement as a search vector and resumes as documents to rank.

- Give weight to each element of requirement (C++:100, C:80, 12yrs:120, 10yrs:100, 8yrs:80, 5yrs:0 etc.)
- Based on the weights, calculate score for each resume.
- Sort descending based on score.

To fine tune the selection,
 - Give weight to candidate's location and work location
 - Current employee 
 - Current CTC/Expected CTC
 - Normalize the score with other candidate/Create percentile

Use insights (if you really want to sale candidate to company),
 - Put weights based on what kind of candidates are being selected by company
 - Put weights on active candidates, how to find them? - another question :)

Comment: Hello, I worked on same scenario you described here, but this works as linear searching and sorting. Time complexity is very high here.

Comment: Correct, you can try [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) with generic weights for candidate columns and employer requirement as search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real algorithm right now, but a way to compute the rank may be to count the number of items each employee has in common with the criteria for the job and put it in relation to the total number of items. e.g: If a job has the criteria: `Java, SQL, PHP` ( 3 items) and an emplyoyee only has exp in PHP and Java (2 items) the rank r may be computed as: `r = (employee_items) / (total_items) = 2 / 3`
You can also add weights to each item in the job description, to identify more important items. So maybe Java is important - it gets 1.5, SQL normal - 1 and PHP less important 0.8. Then employee_items may be `1.5 * 1 + 0.8 * 1`

This is how I would try to begin